# Why does JSLint report 'bad escapement' on this code?

Tags: javascript, regex, jslint

JSLint is reporting a 'Bad Escapement' error on the following code that I am reviewing.

```
var specialChars = "\\(\\)><@,;:\\\\\\\"\\.\\[\\]";

var validChars = "\[^\\s" + specialChars + "\]";  //<---JSLint 'Bad Escapement'
```

Would anyone be able to shed any light on this, and to how it might be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put a literal backslash in a string literal you need to double it:

```
var validChars = "\\[^\\\\s" + specialChars + "\\]";
```

If you're making regexes, it's much easier to use [regex literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 0):

[`Bad escapement`](http://www.jslint.com/msgs.html) is an [`ADsafe Violation`](http://www.adsafe.org/)

Comment: I wasn't really after a desription as to what 'Bad Escapement' was. Can you elaborate on how this is relevant to the question?